# The dot is replacing the decimal separator and it also became the symbol for multiplications. What are the rules to avoid conflicts?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

I've learnt mathematics in France with **x** for multiplication symbol and the comma for decimal separator. Returning to mathematics 30 years after, both tend to be replaced by the dot.

When I write 2.2 am I writing : 2 **x** 2 or 2,2 ?

2.2.5.3 = 2,2 **x** 5,3 ? I am a bit reluctant because I fear we can end to ugly things.

What are rules that have been taken to avoid confusions ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider using a centered dot for multiplication; e.g., $2\cdot2=4$

Comment: Dot as multiplication is upper, then dot as separator. Handwritten can cause ambiguity, but typed, imho, no.

Comment: The centred dot always used to be the convention for decimal separator, but it has been supplanted by the lower dot; perhaps that was easier to type.

Comment: These customs vary country by country, change over time, and differ between the school-room and the research seminar, so there is no universal answer. What, more precisely, is your audience?  MSE?

Comment: Comma as a decimal seperator will not be understood by many English speakers.  Dot for multiplication is an odd convention.  My experience is that it is most common when dealing with integers where it is not ambiguos.  E.g. the prime factorisation of $36$ is $2.2.3.3$.  $\times$ is rare outside of school.  Please don't use * outside of programming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is too broad and too much a matter of opinion.  As stated above, "These customs vary country by country, change over time, and differ between the school-room and the research seminar, so there is no universal answer. What, more precisely, is your audience? MSE?"

Comment: I'm have not a specific audience : I am only someone who is learning again mathematics from books and videos from Youtube. I see these changes and ask for explanations. I'm only in search of the conventions that has been set, the usages that those who are using dot for decimal seperator and multiply have to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The dot that stands for multiplication is usually placed higher like in $\cdot$ , the dot that represents the decimal is lower, like a period. Also in algebra many times the dot is omitted like in 2x or 2(x).
To put a dot higher use \$\cdot\$ but this only works in platforms that support MathJax or LaTeX. This does work in math StackExchange so you can use it here.

Comment: On my keyboard, I only have the dot bottom line.

If I write a `.txt` file, not using Word, Latex, but a simple text file, how do I write a dot higher on the ine ?